# How to group projected revenue (same, daily, fixed amount) by month between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The table I'm using has columns for Revenue_Start_Date, Total_Revenue and Days and I need to group the revenue by month.  The daily revenue amount is obvious (Total_Revenue/Days) but I don't know how to group the revenue monthly.

For example, if a line item has a start date of 8/25/14 and $5,000 revenue for 50 days, then  the daily revenue is $100.  August total would be $600, September would be $3,000 and October would be $1,400.

I'm wondering if I should create a function that inserts $100 into a temp table for each day and then query the table and do a group by.  Is there a way without using a cursor to do the insert?

Comment: August revenue would be 700 i think

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jeff Moden's Tally Ho! cteTally table from here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to
     -- 10,000... enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH 
E1(N) AS (
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS ( --=== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows 
                     -- right up front for both a performance gain and prevention of
                     -- accidental "overruns"
       SELECT 0 UNION ALL
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
),
with DailyRev as (
    select
        Total_Revenue / Days                  as DailyRevenue,
        DateAdd(dd,Start_Date,N)              as ThisDate,
        DateName(mm,DateAdd(dd,Start_Date,N)) as ThisMonth
    from data
    join cte_Tally on cteTally.N between 0 and (Days-1)
    group by DateName(mm,DateAdd(dd,Start_Date,N))
)
select 
    ThisMonth, sum(DailyRevenue) as Revenue
from DailyRev
group by ThisMonth;
```

The Tally Tale (or Number Table) is used to allot the Total Revenue amongst all days from Start_Date to Start_Date + Days + 1. At te same time the appropriate month for each of those days is calculated. A simple GROUP BY query then produces the monthly grouped Total Revenue amounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and a [Table-Valued User-Defined Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to achieve. Then you could create a function based of the recursive CTE and parametrize it as below.

**Create Function:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION ufn_MonthlySales
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @RevenueStartDate     DATE,
    @TotalRevenue         BIGINT,
    @TotalDatys           INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN 
(
    WITH cte_MonthlySales(myDate, DAmount, LEVEL) AS
    (
        SELECT   CAST(@RevenueStartDate AS DATE) AS myDate,
                 @TotalRevenue / @TotalDatys AS DAmount,
                 1 AS LEVEL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT   DATEADD(d, 1, myDate),
                 @TotalRevenue / @TotalDatys,
                 LEVEL + 1
        FROM     cte_MonthlySales
        WHERE    LEVEL < @TotalDatys
    )

    SELECT  YEAR(myDate) AS [Year],
            DATENAME(m, myDate) AS [Month],
            SUM(DAmount) AS MonthlySales
    FROM cte_MonthlySales
    GROUP BY YEAR(myDate),
    DATENAME(m, myDate)
)
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT   [YEAR],
         [MONTH],
         MonthlySales
FROM     dbo.ufn_MonthlySales('2014-08-25', 5000, 50)
```

**Result:**

```
=============================
|YEAR|MONTH    |MonthlySales|
=============================
|2014|August   |700         |
|2014|October  |1300        |
|2014|September|3000        |
=============================
```

**Usage with table(Comment and uncomment as needed)**

```
;WITH cte_test(RevenueID, RevenueStartDate, TotalRevenue, TotalDatys) 
AS (
 SELECT 1,'2013-08-20', 5000, 50 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'2014-08-20', 7000, 55
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,'2014-08-25', 3000, 35
)
,cte_resultset AS 
(
    SELECT   ct.RevenueID,
             ct.RevenueStartDate,
             ct.TotalRevenue,
             ct.TotalDatys,
             CAST(ms.[YEAR] AS VARCHAR(4)) [RevenueYear],
             CAST(ms.[MONTH] AS VARCHAR(3)) AS [RevenueMonth],
             CAST(ms.MonthlySales AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [MonthlyRevenue]
    FROM     cte_test ct
    CROSS APPLY dbo.ufn_MonthlySales(RevenueStartDate, TotalRevenue, TotalDatys) 
    ms
)
SELECT   DISTINCT          
         RevenueID,
         RevenueStartDate,
         TotalRevenue,
         TotalDatys,
         --RevenueYear,
         --RevenueMonth,
         --MonthlyRevenue
         STUFF(
                (
                 SELECT  ', ' + RevenueMonth + ' ' + RevenueYear + ' ($' + 
                         MonthlyRevenue + ')'
                 FROM    cte_resultset rss
                 WHERE   rs.RevenueID = rss.RevenueID
                 ORDER BY RevenueYear,
                         RevenueMonth FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,1,'') 
         AS monthlyRevenue
FROM     cte_resultset     rs
```